# Функция генератор для счета всех строк в файлах определенного расширения

Tags: python, генераторы

не могу понять в чем ошибка, после нахождения первой директории где есть файлы с расширением .py, и заканчивает работу, как продолжить поиск всех файлов в других директориях

```
import os

def search(path):
    for elem in os.listdir(path):
        path_file = os.path.join(path, elem)
        if os.path.isdir(path_file):
            result = search(path_file)
            for path in result:
                yield path
        elif os.path.isfile(path_file) and path_file.endswith('.py'):
            yield path_file



dir = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects'

found = search(dir)

for file in found:
    print((file))
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном конкретном случае проблема заключается в переиспользовании переменной `path` во внутреннем цикле. Замените `path` в цикле `for path in result:`, например, на `p`:

```
def search(path):
    for elem in os.listdir(path):
        path_file = os.path.join(path, elem)
        if os.path.isdir(path_file):
            result = search(path_file)
            for p in result: # замените переменную
                yield p
        elif os.path.isfile(path_file) and path_file.endswith('.py'):
            yield path_file
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное